# Reckless Attack + Sneak Attack synergy?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, rogue, sneak-attack, barbarian

I'm trying to help out one of my players optimize his character. His desired path is the [Unofficial Drizzt Do'Urden build](https://www.ddo.com/forums/showthread.php/150686-The-Official-Unofficial-Drizzt-build) but tweaked it a little according to his taste by going

Fighter 1 > Barb 1 > Barb 2 > Fighter 2 >Ranger 1> Ranger 2> Fighter maxed.

He is a Human variant Dual-wielder using 2 Rapiers with Str, Dex, and Con maxed out at 1st-level and he plans on a Strength-maxed build with his future ability score increases.

He is getting Barb 2 for Reckless Attack which states:

> ### Reckless Attack
>
> ... you can decide to attack recklessly. Doing so gives you **advantage on melee weapon attack rolls using Strength** during this turn...

During our discussion, we came up with a way for him to not need  the 2 ranger levels to get Hunter's Mark and the concentration needed by it (since he will be facing challenges in melee). That was to get 1 level of Rogue for Sneak Attack. We decided not to go for it but it still left a question in mind since Sneak Attack states:

> ### Sneak Attack
>
> ...Once per turn, you can deal an extra 1d6 damage to one creature you hit with an attack **if you have advantage on the attack roll**. The attack must use a finesse or ranged weapon...

Now, my question is, given that Reckless Attack only gives advantage if you use strength, and Sneak Attack requires only a finesse weapon or ranged, it doesn't say you have to use Dexterity:

**Can Reckless Attack activate Sneak Attack?**

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The *Finesse* property allows you to *choose* between using strength or dexterity when making an attack. As such, so long as you're making a **melee** weapon attack and *choose* to use strength for the attack roll than yes, Sneak Attack can be used in conjunction with Reckless Attack.

Comment: Related: Rage bonus damage also has the same requirement as benefiting from Reckless: *melee weapon attack using Strength*.